# Java jars unable to resolve class

Tags: java, groovy

I'm relatively new to Java development...I thought I understood how class path works, but I must be missing something.

Using Groovy, I have 2 external classes referenced by imports. When I execute the script, I get "unable to resolve class" errors. I have the jars for these in the same directory as the script. If I un-jar them, the script works, but jar'd up the script does not.

What am I missing here?

EXAMPLE

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

Logger log = Logger.getLogger("ldap_delete")
log.info("This is an informative log entry")
```

Putting log4j-1.2.17.jar in the same directory as the .groovy script does not work. Setting cp to . does not work. I have to do:

```
groovy -cp log4j-1.2.17.jar myscript.groovy
```

to get the class to load.

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: from the command line - I updated above with EXAMPLE

Comment: Yeah. You have to put the jar on the classpath. That's just how you do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would need to see the script for your specific problem but in general you need to set the classpath when running a java program if it is dependent upon other jars. Here is an example:

java -cp /path/to/something.jar;/another/path/else.jar my.package.Program

Comment: OK yes, but I also thought that the script would (by default) look in the directory it lives in. Which it apepars it does if you unjar the library, but does not *see* the .jar itself.

Comment: Do you have to be explicit with the actual jar files in setting the cp? I thought you could just set a directory...but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: @Bean  Yes.  You need to include the jar file's path and name and its extension as is stated "For a .jar or .zip file that contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip or .jar file." in this [doc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html).