# JMeter: unable to resolve class (org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils) when jar with that class in lib folder

Tags: jmeter

I need to run `JMeter` test plan on the server and I get the error at run time: `unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils` at line `import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;`.

As I understand some plugin is missing on the server JMeter location. After unsuccessfully web searching for that problem pertaining to JMeter specifically, I've found page https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html.

I've downloaded commons-lang package from apache site, it contains files `commons-lang*.jar`. In lib folder of JMeter there are also files of `jar` type, on workstation where test plan works I've found `commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar` jar in `bin` folder of jmeter. Running `jar -tf` shows it has `RandomStringUtils` class. I copied the file to the server to its `lib` folder. But the error persisted.

I've read [Java jars unable to resolve class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814355/java-jars-unable-to-resolve-class) but I assume jmeter looks in `lib` for plugins jar files as there are many files there already.

What else could be the problem? Should I register plugin somehow? From my experience just copying `jar` to `lib/ext` was enough. JMeter version is same: 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I noted in the output of `jar` that I've found another class (also apparent on description on apache page): `org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.class` not `org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.class`.

The below command helped find correct jar on local station:
`echo;find /usr/local/javaapps/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/lib -name *.jar -exec sh -c "jar -tf {} | grep RandomString && echo && ls {} && echo && echo" \;`

It "happened" to be `jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar`. Why such strange (IMHO) location I do not know, but copying it to the server solved the issue. If somebody has knowledge on why that file contained that class, please share in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar` is installed because jmeter-pluigns-manager contains the `StringUtils` Class. There are many other importable classes.

This can be seen by unzipping the jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar file.